# Move or copy in Haskell (vs. C++)

Tags: c++, haskell

Take these two C++ functions and example usages:

```
vector<int> makeVect() {
  vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
  return v;
}

//usage
auto v = makeVect(); //vector is moved

void addFour(vector<int> &v) {
  v.push(4);
}

//usage
addFour(v); //v is passed in as reference
```

No copying happens in either case. This is really efficient.

Here are the corresponding Haskell functions and usages:

```
makeVect :: (Num a) => [a]
makeVect = [1,2,3]

--usage
--Q1: is [1,2,3] copied or moved to v?
let v = makeVect

addFour :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
addFour xs = xs ++ [4]

--usage
--Q2: is the parameter copied or moved into the function?
--Q3: on return, is the result copied or moved out of the function?
addFour v
```

The questions Q1, Q2, Q3 are in the code. Does Haskell move or copy things around? Is there a way to control it? In these cases, how efficient is Haskell compared to C++?

Comment: Everything in Haskell is immutable, so *nothing* is ever copied :-)

Comment: You can't really compare two different programming languages like that. C++ might do something one (possibly optimized) way, while another language (even as closely related as C) might do it in a completely other (but possibly also optimized but optimized differently) way.

Comment: @KerrekSB: There is no contradiction on something being *immutable* and *copied*. Strings are immutable in Java, and you can still copy them, for example. I don't know enough of the implementation of Haskell to comment on that language, but the higher level language must be compiled into low level assembly, and at that point you might get the same effect as copies.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I'm pretty sure that you cannot control whether strings are copied in Java. You can only ever control string-typed *variables*, not objects. (Also, I was being facetious in my first comment...)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think you can pretty much control that. Direct assignment is reference assignment (as you mention just the reference variable is copied), but you can also make a copy: `String s = "Hi".clone();`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Ah, I see. Fair enough.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Actually `String s = "Hi".clone();` throws an exception. This works however: `String s = new String("Hi");`.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues: thanks for the fix. In case it is not obvious I don't program in Java :)

Comment: Note that your C++ example doesn't actually involve move semantics. Even in C++03, most compilers would have used [return-value optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) here, i.e. nothing would have been returned in any way _at all_! The function would simply construct the vector right in place, i.e. below its own stack scope at the memory location that's later used as `v` by the calling function. — But such considerations seldom make sense for garbage-collected languages in general, nor Haskell in particular, because data structures never reside on the stack.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Haskell, values are immutable. Conceptually, it makes no sense to speak of copying *or* moving them. How many copies of the number 5 are there in the entire world? This is a meaningless question. 5 just *is*. Everyone can use it freely, it's the same number 5. Same thing for `[1,2,3]`.

If we look at code produced by a typical compiler, of course there are some copying operations going on there, but those are mostly pointers to immutable regions of memory.

Comment: Does that means that with `addFour`, there will be 2 objects `[1,2,3]` and `[1,2,3,4]` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, the original list can't be changed because it's immutable, so a copy needs to be done.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues, while this is true in this particular case, the reason you give is rather misleading. In particular, if you compute [0] ++ [1,2,3] (i.e., append to the left), no copying of the list [1,2,3] will happen, both lists will share representations. That case works because lists are singly linked. In general, functional data structures are usually defined and used such that copying is minimised and sharing maximised.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg Totally agreed.

Comment: *5 just is.* That is exactly the same everywhere. In C++ the value-semantic type `int` is used to represent integral numbers with some range. There is a single value `5` in the universe, but you can have multiple variables of type `int` all holding the *same* value 5.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Integers have value semantics in C++ but arrays do not. That's kinda the point. If everything had value semantics C++ could just copy pointers everywhere. It wouldn't even make any sense to distinguish copying and moving for example.

Comment: @n.m.: Don't confuse *value-semantics* with everything is an immutable value. That is what I did not manage to get through. Raw arrays are weird, but if you consider `std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};', it models the mathematical concept of a sequence of three elements with values 1, 2 and 3. There is only one such sequence, although there might be multiple different variables in the program representing the exact same value. [I avoided raw arrays only because they decay to pointers in some cases, disabling pass-by-value, but most of what I said is the same]

Comment: Your comment above is contradictory in itself. *If everything had value semantics C++ could just copy pointers everywhere* --wrong, in your own words `int` has value semantics, and the *value* is clearly not passed by pointer everywhere (BTW, Python kind of does this). A variable holds a value, each value is unique, but different variables can hold the same value. The core of the comment above, which I did not get through is that *5 just is* appears to me as mistaking the variable and the value. *5 just is* (the value), but you can have multiple copies of it in different variables.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I'm sorry, I've lost the thread. Mathematical values are not copied, it makes no sense to talk about copying mathematical values. What gets copied is memory contents. C++ variables are names for regions of memory, they are defined this way in the C++ standard. That's why it makes sense to talk about copying them. `std::vector<int>` has (points to) a region of memory somewhere that is large enough to hold three `int` values. That memory must be copied around because it's mutable, and has visible identity (address) distinct from the identity of the value it holds.

Comment: Ok, from a bits and bytes point of view. A variable is a location in memory, the value is the bit pattern. 5 is a value, that can be stored in an `int` variable, that is no different than the sequence 1,2,3, which is a value. Now the variables holding the values can be copied, the value of the destination variable will match the value of the original variable. *Value semantics* do **not** imply that pointers be passed everywhere (if anything that would be *reference semantics*, python comes to mind). C++ has *value-semantics* as a language, for both `int` and `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: "Value semantics do not imply that pointers be passed everywhere" --- if values are immutable, passing pointers is one good strategy to implement this semantics, not the only one possible of course.

Answer (score 7):

Q1: There's no reason to make a copy of `makeVect`, since we know for sure that the list can't be changed (lists are immutable). What I would expect the compiler to do is to make `v` and `makeVect` point to the same list.

Q2: Same reasoning for Q1, there's no need to copy.

Q3: Since the list is immutable, inserting a value at the end requires making a copy. Note that no copy would be necessary, if the value was inserted at the beginning of the list. Once the new list is created, it can be returned to the caller without any need to copy.

Of course this is all implementation details; since data structures are immutable, the program behaves the same whether they are copied or shared. It's up to the compiler to decide what's best, and as far as I know there's no way to control it.

In terms of efficiency it depends. Some operations can be done without the need to copy anything (like adding an element to the beginning of the list), so their performance will be comparable to C++. However other operations need to copy a large portion of the original data structure (like changing an element in an array), and these will in effect be much slower than their C++ counterpart. That doesn't necessarily mean that there isn't an efficient solution in Haskell for some problems, it just means that C++ and Haskell are very different languages, and what works well in C++ is not necessarily the best way to do it in Haskell.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a schematic showing you how you might expect values to be laid out in memory at various stages of the program.

Initially you write `makeVect = [1, 2, 3]`. The layout in memory is something like

```
                1 : 2 : 3 : []
// makeVect ----^
```

Now if you write `x = makeVect` you don't need to copy anything - you can just tell `x` to point to the same place as `makeVect` currently points.

```
//        x -----v
                 1 : 2 : 3 : []
// makeVect -----^
```

However, when you write `addFour x` you need a list which has `4` as its final element. The only list you have at the moment has `3` as its final element, so you need a new list

```
//         x ----v
                 1 : 2 : 3 : []
//  makeVect ----^
// addFour x ----v
                 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : []
```

If instead of appending `4` to the list, you had prepended `0`, you wouldn't need to make a new list. You can add one extra memory location with its own pointer, so the memory layout is something like

```
//        x -------v
               0 : 1 : 2 : 3 : []
// addZero x --^   ^--- makeVect
```

Note that these "memory layouts" are only schematic, and are not meant to represent real memory locations. That will depend on the compiler, and the level of optimization. This is just an aid to understanding, and a method of showing you how it *might* be done.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer, just a small caveat regarding types. If you have a monomorphic (no type variables) top-level value in Haskell, it will almost certainly only be evaluated once:

```
makeVect :: [Int]
makeVect = [1,2,3]

main = do
  print makeVect
  print makeVect
```

But, the example you gave is polymorphic. That means you could ask for two different versions of it with different types, which makes it more like a function that can be evaluated multiple times:

```
makeVect :: (Num a) => [a]
makeVect = [1,2,3]

main = do
  print (makeVect :: [Int])
  print (makeVect :: [Double])
```

In this version, the two `makeVect`s can't possibly refer to the same value in memory because they are of different types.

(The much-disliked [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) was put in place precisely because this behavior, where polymorphic values can be computed multiple times, was deemed potentially confusing.)