# Haskell "copy constructor" invocation

Tags: haskell

I have a situation where multiple `keys` can point to the exact same `value`. Since the `key` domain is quite small, I am using the associative lists `[(key, value)]`.

Does inserting multiple elements with different `keys` but equal `values` force GHC in any way to create copies of the `values` in question?

Taking the immutability of Haskell variables into account, I do not think so, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by point to? Do you have something like `a = 4; b = [(1,a),(2,a)]`?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that :) My worries are, that if the `a` variable is large (think 10 megabytes), having copies of it is just bad for morale

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857165/move-or-copy-in-haskell-vs-c

Comment: @DanielLovasko If `a` is not a value, but a function call (like `f 3`), I think GHC can create several copies of a return value: `[(1,f 3),(2,f 3)]` (and this depends on the optimization level of GHC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, it depends on the Haskell implementation: the Haskell report does not mandate a copy to be made, or to be avoided, it just mandates that the result is the right one -- performance issues aside.

That being said, you should not expect GHC to optimize this

```
let value1 = "hello" ++ "world"
    value2 = "hell" ++ "oworld"
in [(1, value1), (2, value2)]
```

into this

```
let value = "helloworld"
in [(1, value), (2, value)]
```

Just because two values are equal, it does not mean they will share the same memory area.

In the latter example the string `value` will not be copied when put twice into the list, since there's no need to: two pairs will be constructed with a field pointing to the same string. So, only a pointer will be copied.

Saving copies is also the reason why sometimes we do not write

```
foo (x, "hello") = (x, "hello")
foo (x, y)       = (x, "foo:" ++ y)
```

but instead prefer

```
foo p@(x, "hello") = p
foo (x, y)         = (x, "foo:" ++ y)
```

The latter will output the same "pointer" to the input pair, rather than constructing a new one with identical value. (I am not sure if GHC sometimes does this optimization on its own)

Answer (score 1):

You are right,

but the convincing point may not be imutability but laziness. Indeed, if you were to "copy" the value then it "would have" to be evaluated[1]. But this would break haskell laziness.

Also, reasoning about "size" can be treaky in Haskell: is `foldr (+) [1..1000]` the size of an `Int` ? Or the size of the function closure ?

---

1) Stricly speaking, you could imagine copying the thunk but it would not really make sense.